# How to get rid of the Byte Order Marker (BOM) when reading a text file

Tags: rust

I'm trying to read an XML file in rust using the xml-rs library. However, when reading the file it panics with message: `Unexpected characters outside the root element`.

I figured out this is due to the 'BOM' (byte order marker) present in that file.
How do I get rid of this BOM so I can read my file? The author of the library refers to another library `bom_remover` which I cannot find anywhere.

Comment: [decode_without_bom](https://rust-syndication.github.io/rss/quick_xml/struct.Reader.html#method.decode_without_bom) ?

Comment: Hi @Luuk, thanks for the link. This seems to only work for the `quick_xml` library. I'm stuck with `xml-rs` which is a dependency of `georust/gpx` I'm using.

Comment: Maybe you should open an issue on their github page: https://github.com/georust/gpx/issues?q=is%3Aissue+bom+ ?

Comment: Thanks. There is an open issue (and even a PR) in the underlying xml-rs library, but the maintainer insists that they just parse XML and don't read files, so it they declared it out of scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I managed to get this working:

- detect if the file does have a BOM (we should not break files that happen to not have a BOM)
- open the file for reading
- read these first bytes of the file
- pass on the file to the XML parsing library

In order to detect if the file does have a BOM I use the library unicode-bom (`unicode-bom = "1.1.4"` in `cargo.toml` dependencies).

```
// detect BOM
let bom = getbom(&filepath);

let file = File::open(&filepath).unwrap();
let mut reader = BufReader::new(file);

// skip BOM (for now assume always 3 bytes)
if bom != Bom::Null {
    let mut x = [0; 3];
    let _y = reader.read_exact(&mut x);
}

// Parse file using - in this example - the georust/gpx library (which requires a BufReader)
let res: Result<Gpx, GpxError> = read(reader);
```

Plus a simple function to open the file, get the bom info and close it again:

```
fn getbom(path: &str) -> Bom {
    let mut file = File::open(path).unwrap();
    Bom::from(&mut file)
}
```

This code could be improved by also handling 2-byte BOM's & of course proper error handling.

Comment: In case you don’t know, there’s a race condition between testing for the BOM and reading from the file, and potentially interleaved modifications to the file.

Comment: Ow, race condition does not sound good! I was hoping this would not be the case since the opened file goes out of scope when the function `getbom` finishes. Can you please elaborate where the race condition occurs and how I could avoid it? Thanks.

Comment: If some other process changes the file between the two operations, the file that you check for a BOM is not the same file that you read later in the function. It might be possible to avert this with a file-lock, but it's probably easier to just use [`seek`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Seek.html#tymethod.seek) to reset your position instead of dropping and re-opening.